# Facebook video play open webpage

Tags: facebook, video, html

First I don't know if this is the correct place to ask this but I'm too curious how this works. Let me explain to you this phenomenon (at least for me), I saw many times pages that post videos, but when you tap play icon it open a webpage with the video playing, I've tried to investigate about this but the only thing I found is the "Power Editor" from Facebook, but I wasn't able to accomplish the same result.

Anybody knows how to implement this?

I'm attaching you some images of what I'm talking about:

1: **Video on timeline**
[image: Video on timeline]

2: **Webpage loaded when playing video**
[image: Webpage loaded when playing video]

Comment: It is not allowed and they will be banned from Facebook soon

Comment: @WizKid Yeah, but how they do it?

Comment: If you give me your Facebook account so I can ban you first I tell you.

Comment: TBH, I saw this from long time ago, so I don't think FB is going to do that. Any idea?

Comment: Yes you will get banned.

Comment: Seriously if you have no idea how to do it, please avoid to comment just "You'll get banned", I just read that even Facebook allows it when you create an ads campaign. So, what you're saying is not totally true.